# Platt's Notation/Nomenclature for transitions

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, notation

How do you read Platt's Notation / Nomenclature? Where can I learn this?

Some examples where I've seen this mentioned:

> In Platt's notation the transitions are designated as $\ce{A -> B}$ and $\ce{A -> C}$ transitions
>
> The analysis reveals that the $L_a$ and $B_a$ states of the benzene fragments mix with CT configurations
>
> The second $\pi\pi^*$ state has the largest oscillator strength and it is designated as $L_a$, using Platt's nomenclature

$\ce{A -> B}$ seems to refer to the $\ce{\pi -> \pi^*}$, while $\ce{A -> C}$ seems to refer to $n\ce{-> \pi^*}$, but I'm not sure how to read the notation.

Comment: Platt's notation was introduced in the following manuscript from 1949 in reference to classification of hydrocarbons (J. Chem. Phys. **117**, 484 (1949), DOI: 10.1063/1.1747293; Classification of Spectra of Cata-Condensed Hydrocarbons). The rules and origin of their notation are described therein.